# Task.FromAsync and two threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I'm using .net 4.0 and have following code:

```
var stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, bufferSize,
                    FileOptions.Asynchronous | FileOptions.SequentialScan);

var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

Debug.Assert(stream.IsAsync, "stream.IsAsync");

var ia = stream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, t =>
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
    using (TextReader rdr = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.ASCII))
    {

        for (uint iEpoch = 0; item < FileHeader.NUMBER_OF_ITEMS; item++)
        {

            dataList.Add(epochData);
        }
    }

}, null);

return Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(ia, t =>
{

    var st = stream;
    var bytes1 = st.EndRead(t);
    var a = EpochDataList.Count;
    var b = FileHeader.NUMBER_OF_EPOCHS;
    Debug.Assert(a == b);
    st.Dispose();
    return bytes1;
});
```

And it seems that there are race conditions between execution of async callback and end method lambda function(assert is raising). But according to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd321429%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) it is explicitly stated that end method should be executing after async callback is finished:

> Creates a Task that executes an end method function when a specified IAsyncResult completes.

**Am I right that I'm confusing fact of completion of IO operation which triggering end method and fact of completion of async callback**, so they both can potentially execute in the same time?

Meanwhile this code works great:

```
return Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(stream.BeginRead, (ai) =>
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
    using (TextReader rdr = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.ASCII))
    {

        using (TextReader rdr = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.ASCII))
        {

            for (uint iEpoch = 0; item < FileHeader.NUMBER_OF_ITEMS; item++)
            {

                dataList.Add(epochData);
            }
        }
    }
    stream.Dispose();
    return stream.EndRead(ai);
}, buffer, 0, buffer.Length, null);
```

Also I need to mention that returned task is used within continuation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're using the stream wrong. `EndRead` tells you how many bytes were *actually* read. I'd strongly suggest that you need to call this method *before* you can do anything with `buffer` since it tells you how many bytes within `buffer` are actually valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing this so wrong, I'm almost inclined not to answer - you're going to hurt someone with that code. But since this isn't Code Review...

Your *most* immediate problem is that the callback you provide to `BeginRead` isn't part of the `IAsyncResult` *at all*. Thus, `when a specified IAsyncResult completes` doesn't talk about your callback, it only talks about the underlying asynchronous operation - you get two separate callbacks launched by the same event.

Now, for the other problems:

- You need to keep issuing `BeginRead`s over and over again, until `EndRead` returns 0. Otherwise, you're only ever reading the whole buffer at most - if your file is longer than that, you're not going to read the whole file.
- You're combining old-school asynchronous API callbacks with Task-based asynchrony. This is bound to give you trouble. Just learn to use Tasks properly, and you'll find the callbacks are 100% unnecessary.
- `EndRead` is telling you how many bytes were actually read in the preceding `BeginRead` operation - you're ignoring that information.

Doing this correctly isn't all that easy - if possible, I'd suggest upgrading to .NET 4.5, and taking advantage of the `await` keyword. If that's not possible, you can install the async targetting pack, which adds `await` to 4.0 as a simple NuGet package.

With `await`, reading the whole file is as simple as

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs))
{
  string line;

  while ((line = await sr.ReadLineAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
  {
    // Do whatever
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply! As I expected. my assumptions were completely wrong. Thanks for clarifying this. What is related to file reading: I read files about 500KB, so I simply load them into memory so I need only 1 beginread operation. I'm dealing with asynchronous API because I want utilize IO completion port threads and not to waste worker threads. If I will be using Task for reading operations I will utilize worker threads.

Comment: @Sharov Loading the whole file in one go is tricky - for one, you're allocating the buffer on the large object heap, which might give you heap fragmentation trouble. Two, the memory has to be pinned the whole duration of the request, which might complicate garbage collection when not using the LOH. `Task` has nothing to do with worker threads inherently - only `Task.Run` does. When you use e.g. `ReadLineAsync`, you're using the same IOCP threads as with `BeginRead` - you just have a better API.

Comment: Thank you for points about memory! I will definitely consider them. I'm not sure that you are correct about Task.StartNew and thread pool, because it takes threads from pool, except LongRunning option. And unfortunately ReadLineAsync is not available for me on .net 4.0. That's why I messing with old-fashioned async API...

Comment: @Sharov Oh, sure, my bad - `Task.StartNew` also uses the thread pool, as well as `Task.Factory.StartNew` and such. I just throw them in the same bag as `Task.Run` - you explicitly ask for a worker thread. That isn't the case with the natively asynchronous methods returning `Task` - such as when using `Task.Factory.FromAsync` or `TaskCompletionSource` or similar.